# The consequence of $\mu$-measurability from Bogachev's book

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading Bogachev's book "Measure Theory" which is in my opinion is very good book on measure theory. Let me ask you the following question:

> **Definition:** Let $\mu$ - non-negative set function with domain $\mathcal{A}\subset 2^X$. The set $A$ is called $\mu$-measurable if
>   for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $A_{\varepsilon}\in \mathcal{A}$
>   such that $\mu^*(A\triangle A_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon,$ where
>   $\mu^*$-outer measure.
>
> The set of all $\mu$-measurable sets is denoted by
>   $\mathcal{A}_{\mu}$.

One thing began to confuse me during reading. When author takes some set $A\in \mathcal{A}_{\mu}$ and then he considers $\mu(A)$. This confuses me a lot.

We know that $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{A}_{\mu}$ and when $A\in \mathcal{A}_{\mu}$ it means that $A$ is $\mu$-measurable set. But $\mu$ is defined only on $\mathcal{A}$. Why he does not consider $\mu^*(A)$?

More precisely, if $A$ is $\mu$-measurable ($A\in \mathcal{A}_{\mu}$) then why $\mu(A)$ makes sense? and does $\mu(A)=\mu^*(A)$?

**P.S.** I know the fact that $\mathcal{A}_{\mu}$ is $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ can be uniquely extended from algebra $\mathcal{A}$ to $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}_{\mu}$. And this extension is given by $\mu^*$.

I would be very grateful if somebody can detailed answer. Because it is important two understand such things.

**EDIT:** I will divide my questions into 3 parts.

**1)**  Corollary 1.5.8. (page 21). [image]

I was not able to understand this part. He just uses the definition of outer measure $\mu^*$ but not the definition of $\mu$-measurability.

**My approach:** Since $A$ is $\mu$-measurable then $\forall \varepsilon>0$ there exists $A_{\varepsilon}\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu^*(A\triangle A_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon$. Then using monotonicity of $\mu^*$ we have $\mu^*(A-A_{\varepsilon})\leq \mu^*(A\triangle A_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon$. Then using subadditivity of $\mu^*$ we have $\mu^*(A)-\mu^*(A_{\varepsilon})\leq \mu^*(A-A_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon.$ But since $A_{\varepsilon}\in \mathcal{A}$ then $\mu^*(A_{\varepsilon})=\mu(A_{\varepsilon})$ so $\mu^*(A)-\mu(A_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon$. We have that $\mu^*(A)$ is finite so we can apply the definition of outer measure. Is it correct? But I am sure that it is OK.

**2)** [image]

He takes $B\in \mathcal{A}_{\mu}$ but why $\mu(B)$ makes sense? $\mu(B)$ is defined only on $\malcal{A}$ but $B$ may not be in $\mathcal{A}$. This also confusing me a lot.

3) [image]

The same question $B$ and $C$ are $\mu$-measurable sets but why $\mu(B)$ and $\mu(C)$ makes sense?

I guess that all these questions are related to each. So would be very grateful for detailed answer and help!

**EDIT 2:** Also one moment which I have forgot to ask in the previous questions:

[image]

In the above proof note two moments which I have underlined with red line. Why Bogachev writes $\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(A'')$ but in he writes just $\mu(B)=\mu^*(X-A)$. The first is OK and I am agree with that but in the second he omits $\mu^*$ and just write $\mu(B)$. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: Where exactly does he do what confuses you? Could you provide a more precise reference; this is a big book.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, Please take a look at the EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1) he does indeed not use the definition of $\mu$-measurability, he refers to the definition of the outer measure.

2) He just started to denote the unique nonnegative countable additive extension $\mu^*$ of $\mu$ by $\mu$ itself. Indeed, he does so already before definition 1.5.10 when he calls $(X,\mathcal{A}_\mu,\mu)$ the Lebesgue completion of $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$. Using the same name for a function and an extension of it is a widespread harmless abuse of notation in much of mathematics.

3) Same as 2)

Comment: Could you take a look at my approach in question 1?

Comment: I am beginner in measure theory and that's why I am asking quite stupid questions. My approach explained to me why we can use the definition of outer measure. If the set $A$ is $\mu$-measurable then it is outer measure, i.e. $\mu^*(A)<\infty$ and we can use the definition of outer measure (that what Bogachev did.)

Comment: Well, Bogachev starts with set functions whose values are real numbers. In particular, a nonnegative measure on algebra must be bounded above by the value of the total set $X$. He only starts to allow for infinite measures in 1.6.

Comment: And evry set has an outer measure.

Comment: Yes, but outer measure can have infinite value. Bogachev mentions it immediately after the definition of outer measure. In my approach I showed that if $A$ is $\mu$-measurable then it's outer measure is finite. I have done this approach in order to persuade myself. Is this OK?

Comment: No, he just mentions that the definition makes sense for set functions that can have the value $\infty$, but that does not mean the results include such set functions. Indeed, not all results of this section hold true. The extension from a measure on an algebra to the generated $\sigma$-algebra need for example not be unique. However, outer measure on the generated $\sigma$-algebra is one such extension and if you want to allow for infinite measures, you need a proof that works for sets with infinite measure.

Comment: I don't understand most of the stuff that you have written due to my lack of knowledge in measure theory. Hope that will understand it in the near future. But is my approach correct?

Comment: I guess that I have got in some sense. I will add my reasoning right now.

Comment: Indeed, Bogachev defines real-valued set function $\mu$ on some class $\mathcal{A}\subset 2^X$. Then he defines outer measure $\mu^*$ and we see if $\mathcal{A}$ is algebra then $X\in \mathcal{A}$ and since $\mu(X)<\infty$ then $\mu^*(A)$ is defined for every subset of $X$ and $\mu^*(A)\leq \mu^*(X)<\infty$ which shows every set has finite outer measure, right?

Comment: Indeed, that is why every set has finite outer measure. I might add that Bogachev's book might be better as a reference than a first introduction.

Comment: You are definitely right! I have some little background in measure and integration theory and that's why I have chosen this book. In general, the book is quite hard for me. But I am learning a lot of facts from it :) Even though if this book is difficult i like it :) Did you read this book before?

Comment: I use it as a reference.

Comment: Also one moment from the proof of 1.5.8. Could you please take a look at EDIT 2? It is related with my previous question 3.